# Azure logic app costs for EVALUATION of ftp (when a file is added or modified)?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using a logic app to monitor the FTP folder whenever a new file is created or modified.

[image: Pic1]

I see the evaluation block as evaluated 319 times in 24 hours and fired 1 time in the last 24 hours

[image: Pic2]

I wanted to know whether the azure logic app costs for the number of evaluated times? or only for fired time execution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/ - specifically the price for "Standard Connector".